# how to make a <html:multibox> checked by default

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-html

I'm new to Struts 1 so may be its already a resolved question. 
The situation is: I have a list of **<html:multibox>** tag, which are rendered into html-checkbox element when the page loads. I want the checkboxes to be checked by default (without using javascript/jquery).

Comment: Does the multibox iterate the array of boolean field?

Comment: Yes, previously I had an array of String but necessity dragged me to use array of boolean instead. Why just comment, your answer could save many time of mine and others.

Comment: my comment was to see how you used your multibox. I can't answer on unknown information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would set the fields in your `Form` if you want them selected. For multiple checkboxes with all the same `name` but different `value`s, your `Form` should have a `String[]` property that holds all the selected values. Just populate that with the values you want selected by default. This could be something as simple as:

```
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(multiboxField == null) {
        multiboxField = new String[2];
        multiboxField[0] = "optionOne";
        multiboxField[1] = "optionTwo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joeshph ! I tried exactly this code. It works, only when the "multiboxField" is an array of boolean, and I set them to "true". And also in jsp I have to set value="true" in the <html:multibox/> field. And this generally fulfills my need, please revert if any wrong concept I'm applying here.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with a *formname*SetupAction.java class.

Set your struts-config.xml to redirect people who click on your page to this SetupAction.  Import your form class, populate your String[] with whatever values you want default-checked, and action-forward them back to your page.  This also allows you to dynamically populate them, based on DB data or session variables or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I'm following... may be there are some configuration problem with my application. Value of the multibox does not get set.